# how to determine the availability of a URL? (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, url

i want to check if a URL is accessible or correct, how can i send a request and see of it is available?

Comment: What do you mean 'available' - do you mean 'does the iPhone have a signal?' or 'is the server working' ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply rely on Foundation Framework..

From NSURL [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> URLWithString: Creates and returns an NSURL object initialized with a
>   provided string.

```
+ (id)URLWithString:(NSString *)URLString
```

**Parameters**

> URLString : The string with which to initialize the NSURL object. Must
>   conform to RFC 2396. This method parses URLString according to RFCs
>   1738 and 1808.

**Return Value**

> An NSURL object initialized with URLString. **If the string was
>   malformed, returns nil.**

This will validate if the URL does not confirm to specified standards..

Next case , to find out whether URL is accessible, Implement [NSURLConnectionDelegate](http://URLWithString%3a%20Creates%20and%20returns%20an%20NSURL%20object%20initialized%20with%20a%20provided%20string.%20%20+%20%28id%29URLWithString%3a%28NSString%20%2a%29URLString%20%20Parameters%20%20URLString%20%3a%20The%20string%20with%20which%20to%20initialize%20the%20NSURL%20object.%20Must%20conform%20to%20RFC%202396.%20This%20method%20parses%20URLString%20according%20to%20RFCs%201738%20and%201808.%20%20Return%20Value%20%20An%20NSURL%20object%20initialized%20with%20URLString.%20If%20the%20string%20was%20malformed,%20returns%20nil.), override

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

And try to connect to specified URL..If URL is inaccessible above given delegate will fire and see error case there..